# Aggregation, mathematical function & GROUP BY in a single query in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have Table T1 with the below schema:

```
job_id      job_name    queue  memory   cores   start_time  end_time
job_1234    ABC         A_user 51200    20      22-02-2018  22-02-2018
job_2345    ABC         A_user 71680    30      22-02-2018  23-02-2018
```

I want the output to be:

```
ID  f_queue  f_job_name  f_memory   f_cores f_start_time f_end_time  process_month
1   A_user   ABC             120        50      22-02-2018   23-02-2018  201702
```

Where memory= (51200+71680/1024), cores=(20+30), ID and process_month are the static variables that I am passing to the hive script.

Is the below query the right one:

```
select 
${ID},
job_id as f_queue,
job_name as f_job_name,
sum(memory)/1024 as f_memory,
sum(f_cores) as f_cores,
min(start_time) as f_start_time,
max(end_time) as f_end_time,
${process_month} as process_month
from T1 group by f_job_name,f_queue;
```

Comment: Well... Did you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in group by you need to refer to actual column names i.e **job_id,job_name** not the alias names(i.e f_queue,f_job_name).

in your query you are doing group by **job_id as f_queue** i.e **job_id field** and job_name, when hive did group by on both **job_id,job_name** above records goes to different groups(job_1234,job_2345)
You need to change your query to

```
select 
queue as f_queue,
job_name as f_job_name,
sum(memory)/1024 as f_memory,
sum(cores) as f_cores,
min(start_time) as f_start_time,
max(end_time) as f_end_time
from queue group by job_name,queue;
```

in the above query i'm doing group by on queue and job_name which will result

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| f_queue  | f_job_name  | f_memory  | f_cores  | f_start_time  | f_end_time  |
+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| A_user   | ABC         | 120.0     | 50.0     | 22-02-2018    | 23-02-2018  |
+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+--+
```

***Your query results:-***
including job_name,job_id in group by clause

```
select 
job_id as f_queue,
job_name as f_job_name,
sum(memory)/1024 as f_memory,
sum(cores) as f_cores,
min(start_time) as f_start_time,
max(end_time) as f_end_time
from queue group by job_name,job_id;
```

**Output:-**

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+--+
|  f_queue  | f_job_name  | f_memory  | f_cores  | f_start_time  | f_end_time  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+--+
| job_1234  | ABC         | 50.0      | 20.0     | 22-02-2018    | 22-02-2018  |
| job_2345  | ABC         | 70.0      | 30.0     | 22-02-2018    | 23-02-2018  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+--+
```

Probably Your Required query Would be something like

```
select 
${ID},
queue as f_queue,
job_name as f_job_name,
sum(memory)/1024 as f_memory,
sum(cores) as f_cores,
min(start_time) as f_start_time,
max(end_time) as f_end_time
${process_month} as process_month
from T1 group by queue,job_name;
```